# Open an app in fullscreen via Terminal

Tags: terminal, macos, fullscreen

I wonder if it's possible to open a program in Lion fullscreen mode via the Terminal. I want to write a short script which starts a bunch of programs in fullscreen mode, so that I only have to click once to start my working environment.

Comment: Is this the Lion / MTN Lion Full Screen Mode, or a window "zoomed"?

Comment: the lion fullscreen

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here it is:

> /usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "Safari"' -e "activate" -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}' -e "end tell" -e "end tell"

Here it is in a clearer form (but you can't run it this way):

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e "tell application \"Safari\"" 
-e "activate"
-e "tell application \"System Events\""
-e "keystroke \"f\" using {control down, command down}"
-e "end tell"
-e "end tell"
```

And this is it as formatted AppleScript:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}
    end tell
end tell
```

It works by first opening a Safari window if one is not currently open. Then it simulates the <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>-<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> keystroke which tells the Safari window to become full screen.

If you want to make the window the max-size it can be without becoming full screen (i.e. taking up all the space below the menu bar at the top):

```
tell application "Finder"
    set desktopSize to bounds of window of desktop
end tell

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set bounds of window 1 to desktopSize
end tell
```

Which would become this in Terminal:

> /usr/bin/osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\"" -e "set desktopSize to bounds of window of desktop" -e "end tell" -e "tell application \"Safari\"" -e "activate" -e "set bounds of window 1 to desktopSize" -e "end tell"

For Chrome, do this:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    make new window
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}
    end tell
end tell
```

So it would be this in Terminal:

> /usr/bin/osascript -e "tell application \"Google Chrome\"" -e "activate" -e "make new window" -e "tell application \"System Events\"" -e "keystroke \"f\" using {control down, command down}" -e "end tell" -e "end tell"

Hope this helps!

Comment: tryed this, and it helped a bit. it opens the app, but the fullscreen won't work - jsut gives me an error sound. have to run the script twice to go to fullscreen

Comment: @ABLX You need to change the keystroke for whatever app you want to fullscreen - what apps are you working with?

Comment: @qegal I believe entire screen - he mentioned Lion fullscreen in the question comments.

Comment: evernote and chrome. it should be lion fullscreen

Comment: aww my fault. evernotes want ^ + command + f.

Comment: @ABLX - So it works now?

Comment: @ABLX - I fixed it for Chrome. I'll download Evernote and test it out.

Comment: hehe "^" means control :) worked finde with 2 "activate" commands.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work with applications that don't use native full screen windows, but should work with some that don't use the standard shortcut for entering full screen. A few applications have different process names and application names.

```
set a to "Notes"
set bid to id of application a
tell application a
    reopen -- open a new default window if there are no windows
    activate -- make frontmost
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where bundle identifier is bid)
    click (button 1 of window 1 where subrole is "AXFullScreenButton")
end tell
```

Comment: This solution was effective to force Polycom RealPresence Desktop on full screen at login on an OS X 10.10.5 system, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

you can use [browse](https://github.com/75lb/browse) to open arbitrary apps in full-screen mode.. It installs six convenience commands, four of which **open the most common browsers in full-screen**:

Launch Chrome Canary in Presentation Mode:

```
$ ca
```

Launch Chrome in Presentation Mode:

```
$ ch
```

Launch Firefox in full-screen Mode:

```
$ ff
```

Launch Safari in full-screen Mode:

```
$ sf
```

To **launch anything in full-screen**, run the command `ccf` (an applescript sending the CMD+CTRL+f keystroke) after a regular `open` to switch it to full-screen mode:

```
$ open -a Calendar; ccf
```

Should an app have an additional full-screen mode shortcutted by CMD+Shift+f (as Chrome does), use:

```
$ open -a "Google Chrome"; csf
```

**Tip**. If an app is slow to load, give it chance to load fully by inserting a pause before running the keyboard shortcut:

```
$ open -a "Google Chrome"; sleep 3; csf
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's instructions for Google Chrome. (This will open an Incognito window to full-screen.)

Go to `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Content/MacOS/`. Rename the Google Chrome binary to something else (like `chrome-bin`) and create an executable bash script in its place (name the script `Google Chrome` just like the original executable file).

```
#!/bin/bash
open chrome-bin --new --args -incognito

osascript -e "tell application \"Google Chrome\"" -e "tell application \"System Events\"" -e "keystroke \"f\" using {control down, command down}" -e "end tell" -e "end tell"
```

Now, every time you launch Google Chrome it will launch full screen in Incognito mode. I use Incognito mode, but if you don't want that, just delete the `-incognito` flag.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention anything about Google Chrome.

Comment: Also, Incognito mode won't help one whit when it comes to malicious code - it just doesn't store or allow access to cookies and other local (browser-controlled) persistence schemes. In fact, plugins (like Flash) can store and access their own cookies even in Incognito mode.

Comment: +1 for the nice hack even if Chrome was not asked for in the question

Answer (score 1):

Here's an addition to @pasawaya's excellent answer. If you want to execute your applescript from the command line, you don't need to enter every line separately with the `-e` option.

`osascript -e 'multi-line-applescript here'` will work also. Example:

```bash
osascript -e 'tell application "Safari"
activate
  tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}
  end tell
end tell'
```

Answer (score 0):

Keystrokes will fail if you are already in an app that is in full screen mode.

Here is helper script

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "Code"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell front window of (first process whose frontmost is true)
                -- get value of attribute "AXFullScreen" -- for toggling, uncomment this line
                set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" to true -- for toggling, repace true with (not result)
            end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Credit goes here:
https://makandracards.com/makandra/13570-mac-turn-applications-to-full-screen-mode-from-bash